# PHP IF statement not working with _POST array

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

Having trouble with PHP (version is 5.6.27). My problem is I'm never getting into the IF loop, because the IF test fails, I assume because it's an array. I've tried using isset as well, to no avail.

```
if($_POST['product_new_quantity'] ){
  foreach($_POST['product_new_quantity'] as $id => $new_quantity) {
    if ($_POST['product_new_quantity'][$id] != $_POST['product_old_quantity'][$id]) {
      // update the database with new value
    }
  }
}
```

Example data from the form looks like:

```
    // BOF HTML FORM DATA - Formatted to display here.
    // Yes I know It's missing the <> chars!
    input type="hidden" name="product_old_quantity[62]" value="22"
    input type="hidden" name="product_old_quantity[72]" value="11"
    input type="hidden" name="product_old_quantity[3841]" value="64"
    input type="text" name="product_new_quantity[62]" value="16"
    input type="text" name="product_new_quantity[72]" value="15"
    input type="text" name="product_new_quantity[3841]" value="58"
    // EOF HTML FORM DATA
```

This apparently worked before on some prior version of PHP, but isn't anymore... and I REALLY don't want to have to refactor the entire report because these IF statements aren't working.

Comment: have you tried count($_POST['product_new_quantity']) ?

Comment: You've looked at the request and confirmed it is sending as `POST`?

Comment: Try If its an array (is_array) and the size of array (sizeof()) is greater than zero .

Comment: Do `var_dump($_POST);` and see what you're getting from the form.

Comment: No joy...
    if (count($_POST['product_new_quantity'])) {

Comment: edit your question to contain the full html form for this. what you have now is incomplete and pseudo code

Comment: $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($data, TRUE); 
Try it.

Comment: OK, I'll have to write a subset of the code then for a consise exact test example. The existing form is WAY too big and complex to try and submit a question on and I thought my example would be precise enough.

Comment: I've created a small test PHP page to try and reproduce the problem without it being the 25 pages of code, but in my example, the IF statement is working PERFECTLY! Argh!!! The FORM is set as POST (there are a few FORMs on the page, some are GET as they are submitting options to the report for categories, manufacturers, customer groups, etc) to filter the result set down. I don't know if the GET and POST forms are somehow interfering with one another... the HTML source looks OK to me, but I can't figure out why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

pleas check you have set form method post. => method="post"

Comment: Yes it's set as method POST
    <form name="update" action="http://192.168.1.2/admin/quick_updates.php?action=update&page=&sort_by=&cPath=1253&row_by_page=10&manufacturer=0&customers_group_id=3&osCAdminID=" method="POST">

It's difficult to distill it down to the essentials without posting up 2000 lines of code tho.

Comment: if you want to post large amount of variable you must use ini_set("max_input_vars","5000");

Comment: please set the max_input_vars   to maximum number of variable you want to post